# VHDL - Wrong result changing MSB of R2 input

Tags: vhdl, simulation, shift-register, debugging, data

I'm implementing a shifter using a similar strategy of T2 shifter. My implementation is in structural way but I have a problem. My code of Shifter is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use WORK.all;



entity SHIFTER is

    port(   R1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        R2: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); 
        LOGIC_ARITH: in std_logic;  -- 0 = logic, 1 = arith ------LOGIC: fill with 0; ARITH: fill with MSB
        LEFT_RIGHT: in std_logic;   -- 0 = left, 1 = right
        Y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );

end entity SHIFTER;


architecture STRUCTURAL of SHIFTER is

signal mask_mux00 : std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal mask_mux08 : std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal mask_mux16 : std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal mask_mux24 : std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);

signal mask_result : std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);

signal logic_arithmetic : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

component mux08bit
    port (
      A : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  --Input A
      B : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  --Input B
      S : in std_logic;                        --Select
      Y : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));  --Output Y
end component;

component mux40bit
    port (
      A : in std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);  --Input A
      B : in std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);  --Input B
      C : in std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);  --Input C
      D : in std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);  --Input D
      S : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);                        --Select
      Y : out std_logic_vector (39 downto 0));  --Output Y
end component;

component mux32bit
    port (
      A : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input A
      B : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input B
      C : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input C
      D : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input D
      E : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input E
      F : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input F
      G : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input G
      H : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);  --Input H
      S : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);                        --Select
      Y : out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0));  --Output Y
end component;

begin ------- Ricordiamo che, guardando il port map, vediamo tutti i port map di ogni 5 mux a colonne. La prima colonna (cioé l'insieme dei primi input di ogni port map
    ---) riguarda se shiftiamo RIGHT, la seconda colonna se shiftiamo LEFT

 mux08bit_1: mux08bit
        port map (
          R1(7 downto 0),"00000000", LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux00(7 downto 0)); --Se shiftiamo a DX, nel caso di mask00 ricopia tutto R1, ma estende i bit piu a SX a '00000000'. Se shiftiamo a SX invece in mask00 avremo prima '00000000' e il contenuto di R1 sarà shiftato. Creiamo cosi mask00 perché ci serve per il ragionamento che usiamo allo stage 2 e 3
    mux08bit_2: mux08bit
        port map (
          R1(15 downto 8),R1(7 downto 0), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux00(15 downto 8));
    mux08bit_3: mux08bit
        port map (
          R1(23 downto 16),R1(15 downto 8), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux00(23 downto 16));
    mux08bit_4: mux08bit
        port map (
          R1(31 downto 24), R1(23 downto 16), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux00(31 downto 24));
    mux08bit_5: mux08bit
        port map (
          "00000000", R1(31 downto 24), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux00(39 downto 32));



    mask08mux08bit_1: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux00(15 downto 8),"00000000", LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux08(7 downto 0));
    mask08mux08bit_2: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux00(23 downto 16),mask_mux00(7 downto 0), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux08(15 downto 8));
    mask08mux08bit_3: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux00(31 downto 24),mask_mux00(15 downto 8), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux08(23 downto 16));
    mask08mux08bit_4: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux00(39 downto 32), mask_mux00(23 downto 16), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux08(31 downto 24));
    mask08mux08bit_5: mux08bit
        port map (
          "00000000", mask_mux00(31 downto 24), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux08(39 downto 32));



    mask16mux08bit_1: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux08(15 downto 8),"00000000", LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux16(7 downto 0));
    mask16mux08bit_2: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux08(23 downto 16),mask_mux08(7 downto 0), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux16(15 downto 8));
    mask16mux08bit_3: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux08(31 downto 24),mask_mux08(15 downto 8), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux16(23 downto 16));
    mask16mux08bit_4: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux08(39 downto 32), mask_mux08(23 downto 16), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux16(31 downto 24));
    mask16mux08bit_5: mux08bit
        port map (
          "00000000", mask_mux08(31 downto 24), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux16(39 downto 32));



    mask24mux08bit_1: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux16(15 downto 8),"00000000", LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux24(7 downto 0));
    mask24mux08bit_2: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux16(23 downto 16),mask_mux16(7 downto 0), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux24(15 downto 8));
    mask24mux08bit_3: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux16(31 downto 24),mask_mux16(15 downto 8), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux24(23 downto 16));
    mask24mux08bit_4: mux08bit
        port map (
          mask_mux16(39 downto 32), mask_mux16(23 downto 16), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux24(31 downto 24));
    mask24mux08bit_5: mux08bit
        port map (
          "00000000", mask_mux16(31 downto 24), LEFT_RIGHT, mask_mux24(39 downto 32));



    ---------------------------------------------------- STAGE 2 ----------------------------------

    maskmux40bit_1 : mux40bit
        port map (
            mask_mux00, mask_mux08, mask_mux16, mask_mux24, R2(4 downto 3), mask_result);



    ---------------------------------------------------- STAGE 3 ----------------------------------

    maskmux32bit_result : mux32bit
        port map (
            mask_result(31 downto 0), mask_result(32 downto 1), mask_result(33 downto 2), mask_result(34 downto 3), mask_result(35 downto 4), mask_result(36 downto 5), mask_result(37 downto 6), mask_result(38 downto 7), R2(2 downto 0), Y);

 end architecture STRUCTURAL;
```

The code of my Testbench of shifter is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity TBSH is
end TBSH;

architecture TEST of TBSH is

component SHIFTER
    port(   R1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        R2: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); --Credo che quel 5 to 0 sia dovuto a log2(N)-1 
        LOGIC_ARITH: in std_logic;  -- 1 = logic, 0 = arith ------LOGIC: fill with 0; ARITH: fill with MSB
        LEFT_RIGHT: in std_logic;   -- 0 = left, 1 = right
        Y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end component;

signal R1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := "10000000000000000000000000000111";
signal R2 : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "11100";
signal LOGIC_ARITH : std_logic := '0';
signal LEFT_RIGHT : std_logic := '1';
signal Y : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal CK : std_logic := '0';           --Clock signal
begin

LU : SHIFTER
    port map (R1, R2, LOGIC_ARITH, LEFT_RIGHT, Y);

    PCLOCK : process(CK)
    begin
        CK <= not(CK) after 0.5 ns;  --The clock signal is triggered
                                             --each 0.5 ns
    end process;

end TEST;
```

I simulate this design with ModelSim 10.4a.
My problem is: if I change the MSB of R2 to 0, all works, if I change MSB of R2 to 1, the result of Y from simulation is undefined. I don't undestand

Answer (score 1):

This likely should have been posted on Stackoverflow where someone would point out your code in not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Overcoming that by supplying my own multiplexer entity/architecture pairs:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux08bit is
    port (
        a:  in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        b:  in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        s:  in  std_logic; 
        y:  out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of mux08bit is
begin
MUX:
    process (a,b,s)
    begin
        case s is
            when '0' =>
                y <= b;
            when '1' =>
                y <= a;
            when others =>
                y <= (others => 'X');
        end case;
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux40bit is
    port (
        a:  in  std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);
        b:  in  std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);
        c:  in  std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);
        d:  in  std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);
        s:  in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
        y:  out std_logic_vector (39 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of mux40bit is
begin
MUX:
    process (a,b,c,d,s)
    begin
        case s is
            when "00" =>
                y <= a;
            when "01" =>
                y <= b;
            when "10" =>
                y <= c;
            when "11" =>
                y <= d;
            when others =>
                y <= (others => 'X');
        end case;
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux32bit is
    port (
        a:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        b:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        c:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        d:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        e:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        f:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        g:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        h:  in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        s:  in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        y:  out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of mux32bit is
begin
MUX:
    process (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,s)
    begin
        case s is
            when "000" =>
                y <= a;
            when "001" =>
                y <= b;
            when "010" =>
                y <= c;
            when "011" =>
                y <= d;
            when "100" =>
                y <= e;
            when "101" =>
                y <= f;
            when "110" =>
                y <= g;
            when "111" =>
                y <= h;
            when others =>
                y <= (others => 'X');
        end case;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Gives a reasonable result:

[image: tbsh.png]
*(clickable)*

It took getting the left/right select correct in the 2:1 mux.

A little experimenting around and the only way I could get `'U'`s on the output of the shifter was to not provide all the inputs to the bigger multiplexers in their process sensitivity list.

It suggests the problem lies in the code of one or more of the multiplexers, code which you did not provide.

I also noticed `logic_arith` doesn't do anything yet.